# Django clear COOKIES sessionid

Tags: django, cookies, session-cookies, django-sessions

On my website I have no login system. However, users get `sessionid` and `csrftoken`, but I need to clear them up from time to time

Is there any way that I can delete them manually?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you mean by "users get sessionid and csrftoken"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because django enables some [middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/middleware/) by default. This includes, django CSRF middleware and django session middleware. Remove them from your settings.py file

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)
```

Comment: it helped a bit... I stop getting CSRF token, but I keep getting sessionid... =(

Comment: clear all your cookies before trying agin, also try removing everything but CommonMiddleware.

Comment: 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',

Sure, I cleaned cookies before trying =) 
Just two lines left, without first one everything crushes...

Comment: session middleware definitely has to go

Comment: I use sessions in my View, so I cannot delete it... But It looks like I found a way around it, now I don't need to clear it. By the way, thx a lot for your help, deleting csrftoken was important for me )

Comment: Glad to have helped